# Numpy array remains unchanged even after assignment

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have the matrix `x`. `x` has 3 columns and arbitrarily many rows. I want to grab all the rows that have a certain value and change this value for all these rows. Below is an example as well as my attempt to do this.

```py
x = np.array(
        [[-3.1913035 , -1.34344639, 0],
        [-2.54438272, -1.88907741, 1],
        [ 2.12029563,  2.51443883, 3],
        [-2.98150865, -1.53789653, 3],
        [-1.94179128, -3.1429703, 3 ]])
x[x[:,2] == 3][:,2] = 5 # the values 3 and 5 are strictly examples.
print(x)
```

Printing `x` on the last line displays an unchanged matrix. I expect `x` to look like

```py
np.array(
        [[-3.1913035 , -1.34344639, 0],
        [-2.54438272, -1.88907741, 1],
        [ 2.12029563,  2.51443883, 5],
        [-2.98150865, -1.53789653, 5],
        [-1.94179128, -3.1429703, 5 ]])
```

Can I please have some help? I have been searching up this problem for hours but I have not found the solution.

Comment: `x[x[:,2] == 3][:,2]` does not do what you think it does: `x[x[:,2] == 3]` creates a new temporary array and not a view. It is not possible for Numpy do return a view because it would not be efficient. You need to use `np.where` or `np.argwhere` so to create a new array based on the `x[:,2] == 3` result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do what you want is to grab only the column you want to change and then change it.

```
y = x[:,2]
y[y==3] = 5
```

Comment: Wow, that is very unintuitive, but it makes sense.

Comment: or (less readable) as `x[:,2][x[:,2] == 3] = 5`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all elements that matches 3 then this might be helpful.

```
x[x == 3] = 5
```

This might be useful to specify column criteria in

*np.ix_(row_criteria, col_criteria)*

```
x[np.ix_(x[:,2]==3, [2])] = 5
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution, but not for my purpose (which I should have further specified) because I don't want to edit the first two columns